# .Net core with gRPC - data types support and how to debug the code

Tags: c#, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am very new to gRPC and microservice architecture. We have .Net core web APIs written, and they talk to each other via http rest representation.
However we are planning to have communication between internal microservice via http2/ gRPC framework.

We are considering .Net core 3.1 - gRPC template that is available in visual studio 2019.
But I do not have answers to the below questions, any comment will be helpful, thanks in advance.
We want answers for all these below questions before starting the development with gRPC

Considering we use the .Net core gRPC template for microservices communication :

1. How to debug the code locally ? As in comparing it with rest API we can have swagger/ postman to test the rest endpoint, in this case how to do so ?
2. Does it support Nuget packages ?
3. Are there any data types that the protobuf or gRPC does not support ?
4. gRPC gateway - can be written in c# or any .Net languages , if so how ? any existing template from VS 2019 ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you even bother looking at the gRPC page?

1. How you test/debug your API/code really depends on your requirements.
2. Yes. Grpc, Grpc.Tools and Google.Protobuf as pointed out [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/quickstart/).
3. Look at the [protobuf spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3). But gRPC could also be used with other data formats such as JSON if you choose to.
4. With "gateway" you mean the gRPC server? Something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was looking into this documentation. https://grpc.io/docs/ 
For point 1. just wanted to know if we have any  tools equivalent to  swagger or postman (which we use for rest api endpoints) using which we can debug gRPC server methods, track client calls, etc.

Comment: and for point 4. I mean gRPC gateway not server, where a grpc service can be exposed as an http api endpoint and vice versa. Wanted to know if we can write the grpc gateway in .net c#  -

 grpcgateway link - https://medium.com/swlh/rest-over-grpc-with-grpc-gateway-for-go-9584bfcbb835

Comment: Hmm, I do not see why you shouldn't be able to write a "gateway" similar to that from your link in .NET.  But maybe I miss your point. With respect to tools for debugging, I can't comment on swagger/post man as I do not know them. Maybe the [benchmarking](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/benchmarking/) guide is useful?